# DatePicker not updating the state when scrolling to 12 hours later/earlier

Tags: swift, swiftui, datepicker, swiftui-datepicker

I am using SwiftUI `DatePicker` in my app. I have created a `selectedTime` state variable that is passed to the `DatePicker`. I am also using a `Text` component to display the selected time. As such, this text component gets updated whenever the time is changed. This works properly for all the cases, except when the user scrolls to 12 hours later, or earlier (e.g. if initial time is 3pm, and the user scrolls to 3am, or 5:10am to 5:10pm). Additionally, I am using an `onChange` modifier to the time state variable, and call `print(time)` inside the modifier. This also works whenever the user changes time, except for the above case of changing time by 12 hours. What could create this behaviour?

I am also enclosing a basic example of a SwiftUI view that does what I explained above:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TimePicker: View {
    @State private var time = Date()
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.center, spacing:0) {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    DatePicker("", selection: $time,
                               displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
                    .fixedSize()
                    .accentColor(.red)
                    .onChange(of:time){ newVal in
                        print(newVal)
                    }
                }
                .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(.appBackground)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working properly.  If it's not, you are not taking the time difference between your local time and GMT into account.

Comment: @ElTomato I can reproduce the OP's issue using their posted code as is. I ran the code in an iOS 17.2 iPhone 15 Pro simulator with Xcode 15.2. Run the app. Pick a different hour or minute and the print statement shows. Now drag the hour backward or forward 12 hours. No print output appears.

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks.  Hmm...  I don't see it with iPhone 15 under iOS 16.0 Sim, though.

Comment: @ElTomato I just reproduced it with an iOS 16.4 iPhone SE simulator. Maybe it's a locale issue. I'm in a 12-hour locale. I just changed the simulator to a 24-hour locale and the problem is gone.

Comment: This really appears to be a bug in `DatePicker`. I changed `.datePickerStyle(.wheel)` to `.datePickerStyle(.automatic)` and commented out the `.datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())` line. Now, when you tap on the time label that the picker displays, a little wheel picker appears. If you change those wheels by 12 hours, the picker's time label doesn't even  update. So the problem is not simply a problem with `onChange`.